# Date and Time column - shifted one day if entered by Calendar

Tags: 2013, csom, date-time

Created **Task** list, then created first item in it with **Due Date** set for today.
The item looks good. If I access it from **browser** it shows **today** date. If I access it via **SSOM** it also shows **today 12AM date**. But if I access it via **CSOM** it shows **day before today and 9PM**. **CreatedBy** field looks good anyway. So problem with only columns being updated with **Calendar** control. Same issue with all **Date and Time** columns on all sites. Site's **Time Zone** setting set to local Time Zone.
Any ideas?

Comment: So far I added text field with correct date in it. Looks like SP server provides dates using wrong client timezone setting. It's strange as they are the same...

Comment: I wonder if it's something to do with day light savings, if applicable in your time zone?

Comment: It's 15 hours difference between server and client. Definatly not day light saving. I think it could be different time formats, like UTC vs ETC or something else. Sharepoint uses UTC, gonna find our wich one is on client PC